# Telegram Bot how to set parsing mode in curl?

Tags: python, linux, curl, telegram, telegram-bot

Im editing some script for telegram bot, and I only want to add parsing mode html, so it allows me to use bold,italic etc..

I cant seem to find way to adopt parse_mode: "HTML" to curl line

```
 if [ -n "${TOKEN}" ];
  then
    echo "Sending telegram...";
    #Telegram notification
    curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/sendMessage -d chat_id=${CHAT_ID} -d text="${1}" >> /dev/null
  fi
```

Answer (score 2):

`parse_mode` is just another parameter like `text` or `chat_id`. You can use `-d`!

```
curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/sendMessage -d chat_id=${CHAT_ID} -d text="${1}" -d "parse_mode='HTML'" >> /dev/null
```

[Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style)